# tikzpicture fails when externalization is enabled

Tags: tikz-pgf, debugging

In a document of mine I'm trying to use the `external` library. For the record, I downloaded the CVS version of `TikZ`, since I want the better update checks. Anyway, I have a figure in my code which compiles perfectly as long as I have `\tikzset{external/export next=false}` in front of it; that is, the figure's code is correct. However, once I change the value to `true`, then I get the following error (I hope this is indeed the relevant part):

```
 (./figures/region-bounded-by-hyperbolas.tex
Runaway argument?
{ \clip (-3,-2) rectangle (4,3); \draw [thick,gray,->] (-2.5,0) -- (3\ETC.
./figures/region-bounded-by-hyperbolas.tex:83: Paragraph ended before \tikzexternal@externalizefig@systemcall@uptodatecheck was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.83 \end{tikzpicture}

./figures/region-bounded-by-hyperbolas.tex:83:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

When using the 2.10 version this seems to work fine for both boolean values - unfortunately then the update method is poor.

*Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong? How can I debug/troubleshoot  this?*

---

***Edit 1***: I just installed an even newer version of TikZ, 4.8.2012 (following the suggestion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68612/412)), and everything seems to work as expected. Thus, it seems like the issue I experienced was a bug. In case no further insights are provided, then I'll flag to close this questions

Comment: There has been a bug in some CVS version which has been fixed shortly afterwards. I would suppose that you ran into it.