# Update TikZ/PGF on mac

Tags: tikz-pgf, texlive, best-practices, updating

the TeXLive 2012 distribution on my Mac is shipped with `TikZ` version 2.10 - I want to use (try) the CVS (most updated beta(?) version). Here's what I've done so far:

1. Downloaded the the TDS [package](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfCVS2012-05-18_TDS.tgz)
2. Extracted the package into `/Users/username/Library/texmf/tex/generic/`
3. Added `/Users/drorata/Library/texmf` to my `TEXMFLOCAL` variable
4. Ran `texhash`.

These steps indeed installed the newer version in my `HOME` directory, but not nicely. For example, running `texdoc tikz`, opens the manual of the *older* version. My question is **how can I update `TikZ` properly?**

In addition, how can I revert to the old version? Currently I can revert by moving the CVS version from the location specified above and run `sudo texhash`.

I guess this question is relevant for all `TeX` packages, so if this is the case, a general solution will be the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your TeXLive 2012 distribution for Mac OS X is MacTeX 2012, you should get a usable **CVS version of Ti*k*Z/PGF**  with only two steps:

1. Downloaded the TDS package.
2. Extract the package into the root directory of a TDS tree used by your distribution. For example with MacTeX: `/Users/<username>/Library/texmf/`.

`/Users/<username>/Library/texmf/` is the user's TDS tree and, by default, there is no need to call `mktexlsr` (`texhash` is an old name).

To **remove this CVS version**, delete the following directories (where `.` is your TDS directory):

- `./source/latex/pgf`
- `./doc/generic/pgf`
- `./doc/pgf`
- `./scripts/pgf`
- `./tex/generic/pgf`
- `./tex/generic/pgf/graphdrawing/lua/pgf`
- `./tex/latex/pgf`
- `./tex/context/third/pgf`
- `./tex/plain/pgf`

**Note:** To get the latest complete version of TikZ, see my answer to [How to install a current version of TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-to-install-a-current-version-of-tikz/63982#63982)

Comment: Without calling `mktexlsr` it didn't work. Once invoking it seems like everything works. Now, how can I revert back to the old version? Can you please add this to the answer?

Comment: @Dror If you delete the old `ls-R` file in `/Users/<username>/Library/texmf/` and remove your old installation in `/Users/username/Library/texmf/tex/generic/`, the call to `mktexlsr` is not needed...

Comment: If you're on `TexLive 2013` and this didn't work, try to unpack inside the `texmf-var` directory instead. I also deleted the `pgf_CVS` directory and copied the `doc`, `source`, `tex`, and `texdoc` directories directly inside. (Creating a `texmf` directory alongside `texmf-var` didn't work for me for some reason).