# Beyond of the LaTeX

Tags: latex-misc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In what ways can TeX be used beyond document production?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53082/in-what-ways-can-tex-be-used-beyond-document-production)

What else can we create in LaTeX besides aesthetically beautiful typeset documents?
I know we can create theses, monographs, books, we can draw using PSTricks or TikZ and create slides with Beamer, but what else can we do?
I do not know, but how to create mailers? How to create animations?
These are just a few suggestions.
What else can we create in LaTeX?
How to go beyond LaTeX?

Comment: For what concern animations, on the site there are lots of examples; some references: [How can we display fireworks?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88799/13304), [How can we draw a Hannukah Menorah with decorations, using TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85844/13304) and [Explanatory bubbles in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83783/13304).

Comment: Please be reluctant with respect to creating new tags and make sure that indispensable new tags are spelled correctly. For the present question, [tag:latex-project] seems to be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Paper cases for CD/DVD with package cdpapercase. Is that some kind of what you're looking for?