# Where in the world is tikzlibraryhobby.code.tex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, hobby

I was trying to reproduce Claudio Fiandrino's answer to [How can we draw a Hannukah Menorah with decorations, using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85844/how-can-we-draw-a-hannukah-menorah-with-decorations-using-tikz).  However, I do not have the *hobby package* by Andrew Stacey in my local distribution.  After reading [Update TikZ/PGF on mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68608/update-tikz-pgf-on-mac) and [How to install a current version of TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/how-to-install-a-current-version-of-tikz), I looked at the latest [TikZ/PGF CVS](http://perso.mines-albi.fr/~gaborit/latex/tikz-pgf.html) (build on December 7, 2012) but could not located the hobby package in it.  I found [the hobby directory](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/hobby/) but do not know where each file is supposed to go in my distribution.

How do I add the hobby package? In general, what would be the easy way to get any new TikZ package installed in a Mac?

EDIT:  I have used the drag-and-drop (mac) method as described below.

(1) Drag `pml3array.sty` file to `/Users/Username/Library/texmf/tex/latex` folder.
(2) Drag `hobby.code.tex` file to `/Users/Username/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math` folder.
(3) Drag `pgflibraryfpu.code.tex` to `/Users/Username/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries` folder.
(4) Drag `tikzlibraryhobby.code.tex` to `/Users/Username/Library/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries` folder.

I no longer get the `hobby cannot be found` error message.  But, is this correct?

Comment: It's not an official library release but originated from this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54771/curve-through-a-sequence-of-points-with-metapost-and-tikz you can find it in http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files

Comment: @percusse Could you turn that comment into an answer?

Comment: Also on CTAN: http://ctan.org/pkg/hobby

Comment: I guess it's not meaningful to have questions and answers with "where is package X" and "On CTAN. And on dev page Y". So I suggest closing, as Sony got the information, either as too localized or as a duplicate to the question to which @percusse linked.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz I agree, voted for duplicate. And for the users of hobby packege in answers; May I suggest that you put this info as a comment to make sure that users are directed to the package?

Comment: @percusse: I'm going to add this reference in some of my `hobby` answers. `:)`

Comment: @percusse:  I do not see how the so called exact duplicate help me?  I still do not know where each file in the hobby directory go.  (See the link in the question.)  But, if this question is not TeX related then I accept removing it. (I included only percusse as this system does not allow me to include Barbara Beeton and Stefan Kottowitz.)

Comment: @Sony I understand your point but the linked question has a link to the CTAN package in the beginning of the question and alternatively you can run the .dtx file (after obtaining all hobby related files from the launcpad site I've linked above) in your working directory without having the files correctly included in respective directories.

Comment: I've reopened as it's normal to give the OP a reasonable time to make a good case for a question.

Comment: I've also asked Andrew Stacey to include a canonical answer about launchpad procedure. So we'll see. Maybe it's better to generalize this question to all possible cases in TeX.SX products.

Comment: Although you're on a Mac, the instructions at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/86 should still give enough information as to installing a package.

Comment: Have you managed to get it working yet?

Comment: @AndrewStacey: I no longer get the old error message that hobby cannot be found.  However, I get the following error when I try to execute Claudio Fiandriano's answer to the question in the first link of my question.  `!LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}
…
l.29 \fp_gset:Nn \g_hobby_paramc_fp {3-5^.5}/2}`

and the line 29 in the code is:  `\pgfpathcurveto%`

Comment: I just cut-and-pasted Claudio's answer (first code) and it worked fine.  I suspect I'd need to see the log file to be able to help further.  If you can upload it somewhere and post a link, I'll take a look.

Comment: @AndrewStacey:  I still cannot get it to work.  It complains about the line 29 in `hobby.code.tex` file.  At this point, I am losing interest in this. :)  Do not worry about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to keep up with your TeX library is to download the TeX Live Utility. You can find it in several places if you Google it; however, if you download the MacTeXExtras file from the MacTeX website you can find a copy of it there along with some other useful applications for LaTeX. Using the TeX Live Utility you can download, update, remove individual packages from a repository you specify or just use the default. You can also simply update your entire TeX Library at once if you like. Hobby is among the available packages in the list, but is not installed by default, so just highlight it and click install.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think my method of installing (described by steps 1-4 above) Hobby is OK.  In any case, I followed your steps and reinstalled Hobby.  However, I still get the same error message when I try to compile Claudio's code.  The problem is, I have lost interest.  I will probably try to find a solution by next Hanukkah.

Comment: I assume this answer satisfies my question as stated even though reason for asking the question is unresolved.  Therefore, I accept this answer.

Answer (score 7):

The `hobby` library is not part of the core TikZ/`pgf` bundle, hence will not be found in the TikZ CVS. The code is [released to CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/hobby), which means that it will appear in an 'up to date' TeX Live or MiKTeX package manager for 'managed' installation.

If you need to install the package 'by hand', then [from CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby) get the necessary files (all the `.tex` files and the `.sty` file except `hobby_doc.tex`). These need to be installed in your local TeX tree, the details of which vary slightly depending on your operating system. For Linux users, we have [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system), which also has some advice useful for TeX Live users on other platforms. Specific instructions for MiKTeX appear in for example [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex).

One thing to emphasise here (since it is explicitly mentioned in the question) is that, to a large extent, so long as a file is in TeX's search path then where it is in that path is not important (for an exception see [Why isn't kpathsea picking up my local version of a file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79968/86)).  For a user texmf tree (as in the question), it is *good practice* to have some structure and *good practice* for that structure to reflect the "standard" structure but by no means obligatory.

Comment: At least MiKTeX complains, if a suggested directory is **not** in TDS structure, and refuses to add this to the local roots.