# Using PGF/TikZ 3.0 on mac

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing, texlive, mactex

Today I updated my MacTeX/texlive distribution and I have finally PGF/TikZ version 3.0.0!! However, after using the 2.10-CVS version as described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68608/412) for a long while, I want to make sure that I know how to revert to the global installation so I could use the newer version. I guess I have to delete the relevant directories as described in [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68612/412). And then what? Is it enough?

Comment: If you installed the CVS version in your local directory you don't need to do anything other than removing it. Did you overwrite version 2.10 ?

Comment: @percusse: I installed the CVS in my home and didn't overwrite the shipped version. Now I have in my home 2.10-CVS and in the global one 3.0.0. Remove the things in home is enough? Shouldn't I refresh the database somehow (texhash)?

Comment: @Dror: yes, removing it will be enough.

Comment: +1 for the implicit announcement that version 3.0 is finally on CTAN.

Comment: @fpast: I did it, and it seems to work. One issue: I don't have access to the documentation through `texdoc`. In particular, `texdoc tikz` returns: `The file /Users/username/Library/texmf/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf does not exist.` How can I fix it?

Comment: @Dror: I'm afraid I don't know, I'm as puzzled as you are…

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I proceed to use PGF 2.1 cvs or PGF 3.0 and my personal packages with OS X 10.9 and TeX Live 2013.

pgf and my packages are in `/usr/local/texlive` ... 
I created a `texmf` folder in `~/library` and then I placed the different PGF folders in `~/library/texmf/tex`. If I update my packages I place them in `~/library/texmf/tex/latex`.

Normally, with a standard distribution, TeX searches firstly inside `~/library/texmf` and then in the others paths.

If you want to stop to use PGF 3.0 it's enough to **zip** the different PGF folders and to place the PGF 3.0 folders in the trash.

Now with the last TeX Live, you have nothing to do (no `texhash`, etc.).

Another possibility is to place PGF 3.0 or a special package inside a folder with the document that you want to compile. In this case the files inside this folder are used.

Remark: If you want to use again PGF 3.0, the only thing to is to **expand** the zip files.

Comment: Currently in `/usr/local/texlive/...` I have 3.0 and in `~/Library/texmf/...` I have 2.10-CVS. Basically you say I shouldn't do anything? It doesn't seem to hold, for instance `texdoc tikz` loads the documentation of 2.10-CVS.

Comment: For texdoc I think it's normal. In txmf.cnf you can read : % TeX documentation and source files, for use with texdoc and kpsewhich.
TEXDOCS = $TEXMF/doc//
I don't know if it's possible to find the doc pgf 3 before pgf 2.1 without changing the variable $TEXMF. Personally I used often the pgf manual also I use the dock to open the file. It's also possible to use an alias.

Comment: @Dror it's not pgf 2.1 in `/usr/local/texlive/...`and pgf 3 in `~/Library/texmf/...` ?

Comment: No :) I have just upgraded the `texlive` and now `3.0` is in `/usr/local/texlive`.

Comment: Where can I find this `texmf.cnf`?

Comment: The original file is in : `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` and you can define some variables here : `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf.cnf`